# Quick form - checkbox not getting checked

Tags: php, html, css, quickform

I have just started learning Quick Form . 
I want to know how can I create a check box using the add element and then align it at some desired place . 
This is what i tried :

```
$form->addElement('checkbox','testCB1', 'Test my check box',array('checked'=>'checked',value =>'10'));
```

But my checkbox is not checked neither it gets a value of 10 .

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: array('checked'=>'checked',value =>'10') value must be surrounded by ' or "

Comment: @smasherHell : No this wont do !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `setChecked()` method:

```
$form->addElement('checkbox','testCB1', 'Test my checkbox',array('value' =>'10'))->setChecked(true);
```

[Reference](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform.html-quickform-checkbox.setchecked.php)

Answer (score 2):

Read this post: [QuickForm – Setting the checkbox Checked Value](http://raamdev.com/2006/html_quickform-setting-the-advcheckbox-checked-value/)